# how to plot input [-1 0 1] using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

```
my data matrix has 19 rows and 396 columns.

row 1=[0 -1 0 1......]
row 2=[1 0 -1 1 1 0...]
.
.
row 19=[1 -1 0 1 0 0..]
```

how should I code this using plot function in Matlab ? given below:

```
if(bit==1)
   X axis= X++;
   Y axis= Y++;
   /*graph will show increment by 1 */
else if (bit==-1)
  X axis = X++;
  Y axis = Y--;
  /* graph will show decrements by 1*/
```

Comment: Its not clear to me how you want the graph to look. Can you include an example?

Comment: you could use `cumsum` (twice), `ndgrid` and `surf`. Or just `imshow`

Comment: @ mhopeng   foreaxmple: row 1=[0 0 1...] row 2=[1 0 1...]     take row 1         first bit is 0 so point must plot on (1,1) next bit is 0 so point must plot on (2,2) next bit is 1 so plot on(3,1) and so on    take row 2   first bit is 1 so plot on (1,-1) next bit is 0 so plot on (2,0) and so on basically 0 show increment by 1 and 1 shows decrement by 1 ... by plotting this type of graph ...it become easy for me to analyse similar pattern of bit strings ...and those bit strings shows similar pattern will be on one cluster..remember X axis is columns and Y axis is rows ..that's all i want to say

Comment: @mhopeng i want line graph for all the rows..each row represents bit strings..

Comment: any one who wants to answer my question..

Answer (score 4):

```
A = randi(2,10,10); %// create random matrix with ones and twos
A(A==2)=0;          %// set 2 to 0
imagesc(A)          %// plot your binary matrix
```

[image]